# parámetros variables se pasan al pulsar botón, pero no al pulsar intro

Tags: angular

Tengo un componente "navbar.component" con una caja de texto y un botón "BUSCAR". al presionar con el rató nen el botón "BUSCAR" se llama a una ruta y se pasa un parámetro fijo y unos parámetros del tipo "QueryParams":

/buscar2/RUSIA?page=ffff&titulo=idiort

El parámetro fijo es "RUSIA" y los dos parámetros opcionales son "page" y "título". Pero si en vez de pulsar el botón lo que hago es pasar colocar el cursor en la caja de texto y pulsar intro, veo que el parámetro fijo si se pasa (seguido en una interrogación "?") pero los dos variables no se pasan.

https://llqiwmmxp.github.stackblitz.io/buscar2/RUSIA

Paso a url del código subido a StackBlitz.

https://stackblitz.com/github/casiopea2000/pruebas?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fnavbar%2Fnavbar.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Los métodos `ngOnInit(){}` se ejecutan una sola vez, y esto sucede cuando el componente ya esta renderizado. Obviamente si tienes anidado un componente dentro de otro se ejecuta el método en cada componente si lo estas llamando.

Answer (score 0):

Agregale `(submit)="false"` y `(keyup.enter)="buscarHeroe3(buscarTexto.value)"` al form del navbar.

El primero es para deshabilitar el submit el formulario al presionar enter.  Y el segundo para llamar la función `buscarHeroe3(buscarTexto.value)` al presionar `enter`

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" (submit)="false">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" 
      (keyup.enter)="buscarHeroe3(buscarTexto.value)"
      placeholder="Buscar héroe"  #buscarTexto>
      <button (click)="buscarHeroe3(buscarTexto.value)"
          class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Buscar</button>
    </form>
```